# Brush tool painting black instead of revealing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When trying to use the brush tool to reveal a background image I get black or white instead. I have two images and I added a layer mask to the top image layer and selected the brush tool. I set black to foreground. When I try to reveal the image below the brush just starts to color the image black. How do I go about revealing the image below using layer masks and the brush tool. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sounds like you forgot to select the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel before trying to paint on it.

Comment: I was clicking on the layer to ensure it was selected but I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have selected the Layer Mask thumbnail in the Layers panel before you try to paint on it. After painting on the mask, you should see the mask change, so you should be able to see if you edited it.

An example

[image]

***Note:*** If you have a black background layer, this might be confusing you, since the layer mask will reveal the layers below. It will look as if you have painted in black on the image, even though you haven't. If so, try hiding the background layer temporarily.

[image]