# Mask not revealing the background image fully

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am able to perform reveal the background image just like is explained in [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156277/brush-tool-painting-black-instead-of-revealing) post. However, I can still see some of the foreground image. Instead of completely hiding the foreground and revealing the background it seems as if I'm just changing the opacity. The opacities are all at their default 100% so why is the background image not displaying fully. It just seems like I'm changing the opacity of the foreground image to reveal some of the background. Thank you.

Comment: This is a guess: Before painting on the mask,  make sure you choose pure black #000000 as the foreground colour (for full transparency) or pure white #FFFFFF (for full opacity).  If you try to paint on the mask with other colours, it will paint a shade of grey on the mask which will cause semi-transparency/opacity.

Comment: In Photoshop, in addition to @BillyKerr 's excellent suggestion, you'll also want to ensure the mask **density** is at 100% (on the Properties Panel).

Comment: Thanks! Billy Kerr. Ensuring the foreground color was pure black fixed it for me.

Comment: @user220115 - a lucky guess then!!! Glad it worked for you.